# Defining a new command to insert Quine Corners

Tags: macros

How do I define a new command that will surround given text with Quine corners?

I'm looking for something that will take me from:

```
$\qquote{Ixy}$ %Where "\qquote" is the name of the new command
```

to

```
$\ulcorner Ixy \urcorner$
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newcommand\qquote[1]{\ulcorner#1\urcorner}

\begin{document}

$\qquote{lxy}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that I didn't use `$...$` in the definition to avoid possible errors when trying to write the command inside another math-mode expression such as in `$a=\qquote{b}$`, for example. Some people would then opt for a definition using `\ensuremath`:

```
\newcommand\qquote[1]{\ensuremath{\ulcorner#1\urcorner}}
```

so you can use `\qquote` both in math and text modes. I personally prefer not to use `\ensuremath` and to "force" the use of `\qquote` only in math-mode.